# How to avoid hibernate default order by id?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I make this query:

```
String query = FROM Account acc WHERE acc.id = ? OR acc.id = ? or acc.id = ?...
```

I have array of ids:

```
long[] accountIds= {327913,327652,327910,330511,330643};
```

Then I make

```
getHibernateTemplate().find(query, accountIds);
```

I see that the list of accounts I get back from this query is:

327652,327910,327913,330511,330643, obviously , ordered by id.

Any chance I get it back in the order I wrote the ids?

Will appreciate all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it on query level.
You can sort after loading from db, something like this

```
   long[] accountIds= {327913,327652,327910,330511,330643};
   List<Account> afterHql = getHibernateTemplate().find(query, accountIds);
   List<Account> sortedList = new ArrayList<Acount>();
   for (long id : accountIds)
   {
       for (Account account : afterHql)
       {
           if (account.getId() == id)
           {
               sortedList.add(account);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: thanx for response... i was hoping i can avoid this cuz of performance..its not really few ids in question most of the time..

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `Criteria` and its `addOrder`.

Something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria cr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(entityClass);
//Add expressions or restrictions to your citeria
//And add your ordering
cr.addOrder(Order.asc("yourID"));
List<T> ls = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(cr);
return ls;
```

Comment: than you for response, however, im not catching how to define this other id order, where before do i define what is "yourId" and thats being different than simple id? THanx!

Comment: As I do not know of your `entityClass` so I used these terms in general. By `entityClass` I mean the class which you declared as `@Entity`, the one you want to retrieve some data from its table. By `yourId` I mean the property you want to have your sort based on it.

Comment: ok i thaught u were saying that, but that means you did not quite understand what I need, there does not exist a property on which i want a sort.  I want it sorted the way I wrote these IDS in the query :) or passed the ids into IN() clause....but , seems its not possible.

Comment: Instead of using `Query`, use `Criteria` and have your desired ordering as I said.

Comment: not working, just tried it. I mean its working. It sorts by id. (which is initial problem described in question)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to fetch results by providing any entity in `OR Query` or `Restrictions.in()`. As by deafult when you fire this kind of query it will search for the results id wise. So it will give you results id wise only. You can change the order by using Criteria either in asc or desc. And if you want to have results as per you enter id, then second answer is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can only order by column values returned by the query, in a sequence defined by the data type . Wouldn't it be better to pre-order the IDs you supply, and order the query result by ID, so they come out in the same order?

Comment: sorry, but, I still get them ordered by object id in that way, im not sure what am i gaining in that way? or i am missing your point .